# Login issues after upgrading to 22.04.1

Tags: upgrade, login, password

After upgrading I have a strange issue when logging in. When I click on the user account the password window briefly appears, then disappears far too quickly for me to add in my password ~half a second.

The guest account that I had created which has no password has the same problem, but will login usually after a quick double hit of the enter key.

Also, the ctrl alt f3 approach will not accept my user name and password.

As a work around, I have set my login to logon automatically, having done so through the guest account.

Going back to the login screen: when pressing the enter button repeatedly on a user account, so that the password window briefly pops up enough times to make it visible enough to read the message, it says,”sorry, fingerprint authentication didn’t work. Please try again”. This is also the same message that appears when it wakes up, however, that same message is shaking.

Comment: ctrl alt f3 (tty) will not accept your username and password? are you sure you're typing it correctly? note that it's not the name shown on login screen but the actual username like shown on terminal

Comment: Did you enable fingerprint authentication? Do you have an active fingerprint reader on your hardware? Have you made prior changes to your PAM settings?

Comment: I've did a quick Google search, and maybe you can fix it like this: after logging to TTY console (or if you can't, chroot from a live USB), run `sudo pam-auth-update` and disable fingerprint, or if it still doesn't work you can try to uninstall fingerprint, `sudo apt remove fprintd-pam`

Comment: I manged to get logged in through a guest account I previously set up with no password.  I changed the admin account to auto login from there.  I then went into the admin account and uninstalled the fingerprint reader.  It's all fixed now, but now I can't seem to get the fprint reinstalled.

Comment: sudo pam-auth-update and disable fingerprint worked for me on a Lenovo ThinkPad-T460s